# Auto on camcorder

Tags: camcorder

Used to have an old SD camcorder which had a power "switch" not a button. You could mount it out of reach and then flip it on easily with like a wall switch via aux power. Worked nice for video recording at my church. We now have a HD camera but it has a power "button". So now we have to reach or get a stool to turn on every time, total pain. Any way I can make this work like before or a better camera maybe that has a switch. Or maybe just need to get one with a remote?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all mid-range camcorders nowadays allow controlling them from a smart phone over wifi. You can leave the camera on a DC cable, always on (not all models support this), and just connect to it and start recording when you need to.

Not as simple, needs connecting etc, but could help.